# RMI through 2 firewalls

Tags: java, rmi

I want to make a RMI connection between 2 clients, both behind different firewalls, both without port forwarding. is there a way to do this?

Comment: RMI connections are between a client and a server, not two clients. There is a commercial RMI proxy product (mine), but you need to be able to configure both DMZs to use it.

Comment: There's a way to tunnel RMI through ssh -- http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/10/rmi-ssh_p1.html -- which might help, if you can get an ssh connection through the firewalls. I've never used this, though. Alternatively, bring up a VPN.